# Using Dynamic Linq Select - Guid field throwing exception

Tags: dynamic-linq

My Database column name is "Guid" , Since the DB is mapping to many applications and also already in production I couldn't able to change the DB field,

Error Occurs only if Field Name is "Guid"

```
var query2 = db2.Charities.Select("New(Name as CharityName,City as City,new Guid as Guid)");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) you should be able to use the `@` character to escape predefined names.

Example code:

```
var queryable = new[] { new { Id = 1, Guid = "a" } }.AsQueryable();

var result = queryable.Select("new (Id, @Guid, 42 as Answer)").ToDynamicArray();
```

See also [example unit test](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/test/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Tests/QueryableTests.Select.cs#L340)